# Scope of JS Functions outside Node Modules

Tags: node.js

I know that in Node, if you've got variables defined outside your module.exports, it's still locally meaning it's not poluting the global namespace.  It's not public.  What's public is what's defined in your module.

However what about functions.  Do they act the same as variables?  Could function names that live outside module.exports collide?

example:

**myFirst.js**

```
var iAmStillPrivate = "private";

module.exports = {
...whatever code I wanna expose through this module
}

function find(somethingId)
{

    ..some code
};
```

**mySecond.js**

```
var iAmStillPrivate = "private";

module.exports = {
...whatever code
}

function find(somethingId)
{

    ..some code
};
```

do the find() conflict and pollute the global namespace?

Should I do this instead?:

**mySecond.js**

```
var iAmStillPrivate = "private";

module.exports = {
     find: find(id)
...whatever code
}

var find = function find(somethingId)
{

    ..some code
};
```

or doesn't it matter throwing it into a variable?  good practice?  doesn't really matter?

**CONCLUSION**

**mySecond.js** (I'm a mother fu**ing module.  I create an implicit anonymous function that wraps everything in here when I'm 'required' inside other .js files)

```
`var iAmStillPrivate = "private";` (no I'm scoped to the module, the root anonymous function that is...)
```

(module.exports - I'm allowing this stuff to be public.  When I say public in node,that is...public in that the stuff in here is accessible to other modules in other .js files or whatever.)

```
module.exports = {
...whatever code 
}
```

(I'm still a function scoped to the module but I've not been exported so I'm not available to other modules, I only belong to the module (the root anonymous function)

```
function find(somethingId) 
{

    ..some code
};
```

Comment: Functions inside modules are just that, inside modules.

Comment: You aren't getting my question.

Comment: I think I am. I think you're not getting what a module is. The file is the module.

Comment: module.exports is the module definition and that's what is imported...not the .js file meaning node module.  .js file is just a file that holds code that you can require.   What's imported is module.exports value.

Comment: Module exports is what the MODULE EXPORTS. I think that's why they called it `module.exports` because it's what the module exports.

Comment: I know that.  I'm talking about code OUTSIDE that. IN the .js file.

Comment: ... The entire file is wrapped in a function. That's the module. What the module *exports* is in `module.exports`, which is why they called it `module.exports` and not just `module`.

Comment: then what's the diff between the module function and module.exports?

Comment: One is the module. One is what the module exports.

Comment: ok so it's scope.  Function wraps the public scoped objects.  Public scoped objects are defined inside module.exports.  Anything out side module.exports lie as members of the module function.  Members of each module do not conflict with each other.

Comment: The function wraps *everything*. That's why you can't access it unless you export it.

Comment: right see my last comment, every sentence is correct, correct?

Comment: so there's no way for function members to conflict because they're in their own function scopes

Comment: No, you said the function wraps the public scoped objects. Nothing is "public-scoped" until you export it.

Comment: Correct: module functions are just that, inside modules.

Comment: that is what I said right after you just didn't read it the same.  I said the publicly scoped objects are defined in your module.exports object.

Comment: No, you said "module.exports is the module definition and that's what is imported" but the first part of that sentence isn't true. The file is the module definition, and modules have exports.

Comment: Let me try to communicate better.  For some reason it's the way I talk about stuff.  1) Every .js file is a module 2) A module is a function, therefore the entire.js file is a "module"  3) A module (function) contains objects such as module.exports and other local variables and whatever.  The module.exports defines what you want to expose publicly to other modules while the rest of the members in a module function are scoped to the function implicit function for that .js file.  So there's no way for a module's variables or local functions to conflict.

Comment: We need beer icons on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions in each module of NodeJs are local for that module and do not conflict with functions of other modules with the same name.
Think about it as though the module was wrapped in a function.

Also you really don't need to define a variable for your functions because at the end it doesn't matter, the scope of functions and variables of these two lines are the same and local for module:

```
var find = function find(somethingId) ...

function find(somethingId) ...
```

### Side Question

Also in you comment you asked about this scenario:

> what if I have a function in global scope and a module also has a private function with the same name. do they conflict?

What happens is that inside your module any call to that function will trigger the `local` function not the `global` one. once you are outside of that module or inside another modules any call to that function will trigger the `global` function.

Let's look at it with an example. suppose our Node app starting point is `index.js` here its content:

```
echo('one');

require('./include.js')

echo('three');

function echo(txt){
  console.log("we are in index.js", txt);
}
```

And here is a module called `include.js`:

```
echo('two');

function echo(txt){
  console.log("we are in include.js", txt);
}
```

if you run this app using `node index.js` command, the output should be:

```
we are in index.js one
we are in include.js two
we are in index.js three
```

See? All the functions are there working as I explained earlier.

Comment: also after my last comment, can you check my conclusion, see the updated post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85156/discussion-between-arash-milani-and-we-do-tdd).

Answer (score 0):

Beause i need 50 rep to comment.

@ arash milani.
Not on stackoverflow so -10000

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34669134)